# In a google maps API info window pop up, when are images fetched?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#introduction describes an InfoWindow.

Do images (e.g. JPEG photos) in the content of the InfoWindow get loaded on map load or on marker click?

E.g. If I have 10,000 markers on a map, each with an InfoWindow with a photo, I assume the photos only get loaded by the browser when a user clicks a marker?

Comment: Add them to the map, open browser's developer tools, check what is loaded and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A info window is just another DOM element. If you place a `<img/>` in one, it only will get loaded if you open the info window (then the window element is added to the document).